# http request not responding to POST option set (PHP)?

Tags: php, http, request

I get this anoying error from Userapp.io service:

> {"error_code":"INVALID_HTTP_METHOD","message":"Cannot execute request.
>   Request must be 'POST' or 'OPTIONS'."}

I tells me that the following code that i wrote

```
    $options = array("https" => array(
                    "method" => "POST",
                    "header" => "Authorization: " .$access_token . "\r\n" . 
                    "Content-Type: application/json" . "\r\n" . 
                    "Content-Length: 56" . "\r\n" . 
                    "Host: api.userapp.io:443" . "\r\n"),
                    "content" => $data
    );
```

is not being used by `$context = stream_context_create($options);`

Does anybody knows why it will reflect?

I use `$fp = fopen($url, 'r', true, $context);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to some special way of handling https request: 
check this out:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php#74795

Comment: hi, thanks for info. I get this error when i change to http from https HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout